# Android Realm - copyToRealmOrUpdate clears RealmList

Tags: android, realm

I have a Realm object "TaskEntity" which has `RealmList` field.

```
public class TaskEntity extends RealmObject {
    ...
    private RealmList<ContextEntity> contexts;
}
```

I make new instance of this entity through constructor and copy values of fields from `Realm` object.

```
TaskEntity task = mRealm.where(TaskEntity.class).findFirst();
TaskEntity newTask = new TaskEntity();
newTask.setId(task.getId());
newTask.setName(task.getName());
newTask.setContexts(task.getContexts()); //copying of RealmList
```

When user makes some changes and wants to save it I call `copyToRealmOrUpdate`.

```
mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newTask);
    }
});
```

Sometimes old state has several items in RealmList and user doesn't make changes in that field. So when I call `copyToRealmOrUpdate`, `RealmList` becomes empty.

```
newTask.getContexts().size(); // 2 items
mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newTask);
    }
});
newTask.getContexts().size(); // 0 items
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why this approach? Why not update `task` instead of overwriting it with `newTask`?

Comment: Because user needs opportunity to discard changes. In that case I can ignore changes and don't call `copyToRealmOrUpdate`

Comment: You can also `beginTransaction()` and if the user wants to discard changes, use `cancelTransaction()`

Comment: Well, I will try this way

Comment: This approach works pretty good. But I still don't know why `copyToRealmOrUpdate` was clears `RealmList`. Maybe it's some kind of bug of Realm.

Comment: `copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj)` clears the list if it is empty in `obj`. That is the intended behaviour.